# Read a file (containing letters and digits) into two 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help to read a text file into two 2-D arrays.
Example for the file data:(each name with its score in one line)

```
Jon   78
Adam   45
Merry  56
```

I need to read the letters into one array and the digits into other one.
I succeed to read the whole file into one 2-D array:

```
FILE *infile;
int  i , j, c,  nl = 0, cr = 0, col = 0, row = 0;
infile = fopen("D.txt", "r");
while (fscanf(infile, "%c", &c) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '\n')
        nl++;
    if (c == '\r')
        cr++;

    col++;

    if (c == '\n')
        row++;
        putchar(c);}
col = (col - (nl + cr));
col = (int) (col/row);
row = row - row;
 char sn[row][col];
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            fscanf(infile,"%c", &sn[i][j]);}}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?